# React Apollo data directly to React Context

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-context

I have a standard react-apollo graphql query:

```
<Query query={USER_QUERY} variables={{ user: userId }}>
  {
    ({ loading, error, data }) => {
    if (loading) return <p>Loading…</p>
    if (error) return <p>An Error Occurred</p>
    return (
      <div>
        Data back from gql available!
      </div>
    )}
  }
</Query>
```

But I'm not sure how to share the fetched data via React context. I know I can drop the data right into a provider:

```
<Query query={USER_QUERY} variables={{ user: userId }}>
  {
    ({ loading, error, data }) => {
    if (loading) return <p>Loading…</p>
    if (error) return <p>An Error Occurred</p>
    return (
      <MyContext.Provider value={data}>
        Data back from gql available!
      </MyContext.Provider>
    )}
  }
</Query>
```

But it seems like this might not provide the best capability for handling caching and other data-related problems. Is there a more standardized way to handle what must be a fairly common use case?

Answer (score 1):

I had assumed this was an alternative with react-apollo - I had missed that react-apollo extends the basic client library, in which you can simply do this:

```
client.query({
  query: gql`
    query {
      user {
        id
      }
    `,
    variables: { ...vars },
  })
  .then(res => console.log(res)
  .catch(err => console.log('an error occurred: ', err)
```